# When to light the Shamash when lighting Menorah?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, priorities, menora-chanukia

When lighting my Menora, saying the relevant Brachot, and lighting the Shamash, what order should I follow?

I think the best way is:
1. Shamash
2. Brachot
3. Chanukah-Lights

But someone said, the right way is:
1. Brachot
2. Chanukah-Lights
3. Shamash

What do poskim say?

Comment: I never heard the second opinion. Why then would it be called the Shamash!?

Comment: Answer of Imanonov here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23/what-is-the-appropriate-use-of-the-shamash-on-an-oil-menora says so. But it's unclear what ashkenazic Poskim would say.

Comment: Who cares when you light the Shamash?

Comment: @DoubleAA Rav Essas here http://evrey.com/sitep/askrabbi2/index2.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=8050&Itemid=48 says it in Russian.

Comment: Shamash last?  I thought you were supposed to *use* the shamash to light the rest?

Comment: based on @WAF's answer, but I think the second case brought in the question may be talking about when there Shamash is not the one used to light the candles. For example, an Oil Menorah that also has an Oil Shamash. As described in that answer, this is used as extra light to prevent accidental usage of mitzva lights. - Since one fulfills one's obligation by even lighting one light, if one lights the Oil Shamash with his candle Shamash he may no longer be able to say the blessing. If so, he should first light the mitzvah candles before lighting the Oil Shamash. -- I have not seen this anywhere

Comment: @Menachem By that logic he shouldn't light the candle that he will use to light the other candles either. Clearly intent is at play here.

Comment: @DoubleAA: The Candle Shamash is clearly not a mitzvah candle because it is used to light other candles.

Comment: @Menachem That is not an indication of non-mitzva candle, as we paskin מדליקין מנר לנר. Furthermore, I'm not sure what you mean by "clearly". Clearly to whom? A viewer outside? How is it more or less clear to anyone else what a random light in a window is for?

Comment: @DoubleAA: The Rema (674:1) rules that we don't light from one light to another light.

Comment: @Menachem I know. It's a chumra (and many Achronim question how good a chumra it is). And that's only about two candles in the same person's menora. Two people each lighting one _can_ light from each other. The fact is we paskin that you can light chanukkah candles from each other; the only argument is what is considered a chanukkah candle.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23/what-is-the-appropriate-use-of-the-shamash-on-an-oil-menora

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think an answer can be inferred from the *Aruch Hashulchan*'s detailed discussion in [673:9-12](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%92#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A8.D7.A2.D7.92_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.98). He sources the *Tur*, who says explicitly that there are two *non-mitzva* lights in addition to the official *Chanuka* lights. One is a "helper light" called the *shamash* and the other is an "extra" one.

The *shamash* is used to light the other light(s). In practice this one *must* be lit first. As the general principle of saying *brachos over la'asiyas mitzvos* (i.e. immediately before performance) applies here, I would assume that the *b'rachos* would be recited in between the *shamash* and the real lights.

The extra light serves the purpose of ensuring that the increased visibility in the room is attributable to a non-*mitzva* source and therefore usable. The *Tur* clearly says that this light is lit after¹ the *mitzva* light(s) and is not called a *shamash*.

The two primary transmitters of the *Tur*'s words - Rav Yosef Karo and Rav Moshe Iserles disagree about how to differentiate this light from the others, but it does seem that they conflate it functionally with the *shamash*, resulting in only one candle. The *Aruch Hashulchan* concludes by recommending satisfying all aforementioned opinions by using a *shamash* and then leaving it near to but distinctively from the other light(s).

---

¹It does appear interestingly that it *should* be the last one lit so that the official lights are physically grouped together but that designating one of the middle lights as the extra one might not invalidate anything.

Comment: So in the end since we only light one non-mitzvah candle, the question as to whether it is lit first or last cannot be answered - is it primarily a shamash and so should be lit first, or is it primarily the extra light and should be lit last. Unless we say that since it is **also** a shamash and should be used to light the other candles, then this would mandate that it be lit first. (I think this argument is the most reasonable, and FTR I light it first)

Comment: I came to the conclusion of your last possibility as well due to the physical constraints that definition imposes.

Comment: From the text in the Shulchan Aruch (673:1), it does not appear that the Mechaber and Remah are talking about the same candle. Mechaber == _"ונוהגים להדליק נר נוסף כדי שאם ישתמש לאורה יהיה לאור הנוסף שהוא אותו שהודלק אחרון"_ -- an extra candle, lit last. Remah == _" ובמדינות אלו אין נוהגים להוסיף רק מניח אצלן השמש שבו מדליק הנרות"_ -- the Shamash, lit first. ---- http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Shulchan_Aruch/Orach_Chaim/673

Comment: @Menachem I should reword that in my answer but I think that's why Aruch Hashulchan called using one candle for both יציאה לכל הדעות.

Answer (score 0):

R’ Shmuel Kaminetzky in Kobetz Halachos says, if one **mistakenly** lights the shamash before the other candles it is not considered a hefsek between the brocha and the lighting. Clearly he holds one should light the shamash after the other candles.

Comment: I didn't look at the source inside, but is it possible that what he meant was that you should light the shamash *before* the other candles, but say the blessing *after* lighting the shamash? The mistake would then be having lighted the shamash after the blessing, not before the other candles

Comment: Don’t believe that to be the case because his words are “if one makes a brocha and mistakenly lights the shamash before the other candles it is not considered a hefsek”. If you are supposed to light the shamash beforehand the mistake would not be lighting it before the candles, but rather lighting it after the brocha.

Comment: Yehoshua, excellent reasoning imho but @ba is right, see Yalkut Yosef 676:10 (there are more factors to take into account than you included in your reasoning)

Answer (score 0):

Yalkut Yosef rules that Sefardim, in contrast to Ashkenazim, light the *shammash* last. See 673:26.